# Run one subprocess after another in a single call that works in the background

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

To run a *subprocess* in the background without disturbing the continuity of the main code I call the Python file like this:

```
Popen(['secondary.py'], shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True)
```

Is there any way I can use this call to run that first file(`'secondary.py'`) and then run another file (`'tertiary.py'`) when it finishes the process?

Something like for example:

```
Popen(['secondary.py','tertiary.py'], shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True)
```

Note:

I can't call one below the other like this:

```
Popen(['secondary.py'], shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True)
Popen(['tertiary.py'], shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True)
```

Because they would become two separate *subprocesses*, which is not my expected goal, I need to finish one and then run the other.

Comment: Keep in mind that running `secondary.py` with `shell=True` isn't a reliable way to *execute* a python file. This opens the file using the user's "default application" for python files, which might be a text editor or an IDE. Use `[sys.executable, 'secondary.py']` instead, without `shell=True`.

Comment: Modified, thanks for the comment!

Comment: In most shells, the semicolon between two commands means to run one command and then the next.  Can you use `Popen('secondary.py ; tertiary.py', shell=True, ....)`

Comment: Hi @FrankYellin i run the attempt but this error appear ```'secondary.py ; tertiary.py' is not recognized as an internal command
or external, an operable program or a batch file.```

Comment: The error message suggests that you forgot the `shell=True`...?

Comment: Correct @tripleee you nailed it, I had removed it to update the method indicated by Aran-Fey!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subprocess.run` waits until the command is complete. You could create a background thread that runs all the commands you want in a row.

```
import threading
import subprocess

def run_background():
    subprocess.run(['secondary.py'], shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True)
    subprocess.run(['tertiary.py'], shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True)

bg_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_background)
bg_thread.start()
```

Because this was not marked as a daemon thread, the main thread will wait until this thread has completed while exiting the program.

Comment: Hi @tdelaney this error appears ```assert group is None, "group argument must be None for now"
AssertionError: group argument must be None for now``` as I have no knowledge with Threading, could you add the reason why this happened?

Comment: oops, rookie mistake on my part. `Threading.thread` has a required but not used positional argument. Its annoyed programmers for decades now.

Comment: `shell=True` seems unnecessary here, as highlighted in comments on the question.

Comment: @tripleee - Yes, unneeded in this example. I assume that something else shell-like is going on in the real code.